# toggle jquery-mobile ui button's icon inside backbone view

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone-views

I have a problem where I change my jquery-mobile attribute with the following code:

```
 this.$("#" + idOfButton).attr('data-icon', "check")
     .find('.ui-icon')
     .addClass('ui-icon-' + "check")
     .removeClass('ui-icon-' + "grid");
```

When this code is run, I see updates in all the classes and data-role in my chrome debugger. I am doing this inside a backbone view.

The problem is I never see the changes happen in my actual view and the views still display the old grid icon.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your selector. It is sufficient to use `$("#" + idOfButton)` to select the element. So, to change the icon:

```
$("#" + idOfButton).removeClass('ui-icon-grid').addClass('ui-icon-check');
```

Just for reference: jQuery Mobile has sort of a 'duality' for buttons, which can be declared both with `<input>` and `<a>` tags. So, changing icons can be done in two ways.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="button" data-icon="grid" id="test_input" value="Test with 'input' tag"/>
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="grid" id="test_a">Test with 'a' tag</a>

<a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="change">Change icon</a>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).on("click", "#change", function()
{
    $("#test_input").button("option", "icon", "check");
    $("#test_a").removeClass("ui-icon-grid").addClass("ui-icon-check");
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byUf4/)**

---

**Update referred to jQuery Mobile 1.1.2 / 1.2.0**

Enhancement is different, this works:

```
$("#test_a").find(".ui-icon").removeClass("ui-icon-grid").addClass("ui-icon-check");
```

but you cannot use `$(document).on()` to attach the event. Use instead:

```
$("#change").live("click", function()
{
    $("#test_a").find(".ui-icon").removeClass("ui-icon-grid").addClass("ui-icon-check");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back Sga. I tried your suggestion. I am still using the <a> tag but take a look at the following image which will show you the icons during the debugging and then after it is done with manipulating everything. 
http://imgur.com/rBMMQ8t

Comment: Also, I have to mention, we are using jquery-mobile 1.1.2

Comment: version `1.1.2` is quite obsolete (March 25, 2013). Is updating an option? Meanwhile, I see what I can do

Comment: Sga you don't need to worry about the event because I using backbone's event. So, whenever it registers a tap, it fires my function correctly. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: Ok I tried your suggestion. Well at least this time it changes icon but instead of just showing check, it is showing the grid as well as the settings icon just like in the first picture I sent earlier. I am wondering where is all that coming from? This seems really weird.

Comment: maybe additional style is causing this. Please edit your answer with the full button DOM (with grid icon)

Comment: I think I know why it is showing those overlapping icons. jquery-mobile-ui uses sprites for their icons. It is a single file with these small icons inside it. So, when it needs to get an icon, it just goes and finds that location of the icon, draws a box, and gets the icon. I think somewhere in their code, it is messing itself up and getting two icons instead. So that is why we see the check icon with the settings icons.

Comment: I just don't know if there is a fix for this.

Comment: I manually just set the width and it seems to work for now. But I do not think it is an elegant solution. If anybody has one, please let me know.